# ASPNET Execute code since web published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm developing a SignalR WebServer and I need it to execute some code since the publication on IIS and before any client connects. IS that possible?

I'm trying to log the Global.asax.cs file to know if it works:

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    ILogger log = new ELLogger(typeof(WebApiApplication));

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        log.Information("App start");
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can't do that, `Application_Start()` is called once for the lifetime of the application, more about lifetime you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx . Describe what exactly want to do.

Comment: WebServer will connect to different PLCs via OPC and send information to clients using SignalR. So I need to connect to PLCs when application starts

Comment: So why not use `Application_Start()`? You need call your method once on start application? You can always call  `Application_OnStart()`, this function is called before any `.asp` files are processed.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do on my sample code writting a trace. Written trace shows on VS debugging but not when I publish on the server

Comment: Try use `Application_OnStart()`, this runs once when your app receives the first HTTP request and before any text,graphics are rendered and sent to the user's browser.